# Question about proof of property of autocovariance function

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation, stochastic-processes

I am studying time series, I have a small trouble with the proof of one of the proofs of the autocovariance function:

I need to show that $$|\gamma(h)|\leq \gamma(0)$$

I am considering complex-valued random variables:

First I have that $|\gamma(h)|=|\langle X_{k+h}-E[X_{k+h}] ,X_{k}-E[X_k] \rangle |$. Then I apply the Cauchy Schwarz inequality and I get that the last expression is smaller or equal than: $$\leq||X_{k+h}-E[X_{k+h}]|| \ ||X_k-E[X_k]||$$ After this step I donpt have clear why the last expression is equal to $$||X_k-\mu||^2$$

I know that since the process considered in the definition of the autocovariance function is stationary then $E[X_k]=E[X_{k+h}]=\mu$ since it does't depends on $k$. But I don't have clear what happen with $X_{k+h}$

Comment: Hint: what does "stationary" mean?